# Creating Several Branches in Git

Tags: git, bitbucket, branch

We have a branch called BUGFIX_3_10 at work. Which means we do the development of bugfixes here for the 3.10 version of our product.

For my new bugfix task ABC, I create a new branch from this BUGFIX_3_10 branch. Afterwards I push it and create Pull Request for the review of the Senior Software Engineer. Everything until here is fine, right?

But he is so busy and he replies my PR vey late usually. And I have a 5 more bugfixes waiting in my task list. I am just waiting for him to approve or give a feedback for hours. I feel like instead of wasting my time I should focus next coming tasks.

Before I merge ABC into BUGFIX_3_10 (because I am waiting for an approval), if I create a new branch for my next task XYZ from again BUGFIX_3_10, then when I merge XYZ my code will miss the changes for ABC. Then when I get my approval for ABC from my senior developer, then that code will miss the changes for XYZ. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: If they are not interrelated, that should not be a problem. In any case, after one of the branches is merged, you could rebase the other branch before it is merged so that you get the latest changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! We are using Fork to deal with merge, pull push etc. 

For rebase I see 2 options: "Rebase release/BUGFIX_3_10 on bugfix/ABC" and "Rebase Intecarctively release/BUGFIX_3_10 on bugfix/ABC". 

Which one should I go with do you have any idea?

Comment: I honestly don't know what they _really_ mean cause I don't know the application (Fork?). So... say you start 2 branches, branchA and branchB from the same revision of BUGFIX_3_10. So, you go with branchA, finish it, send it over for review. Start working on branchB. When branchA is accepted and merged into BUGFIX_3_10, you rebase branchB on top of `BUGFIX_3_10` (which already has the code for branchA). You could even start branchB _on top_ of branchA but then moving branches around is a little trickier (not too difficult anyway, as long as the git *basics* are already laid down in your ROM).

Comment: "Fork" is not relevant, but neither are branch names, really. What *really* matter are commit hash IDs. Branch names do matter in that we use them to *find* the commit hash IDs, but once we've found the hash IDs, nothing else cares about the names (well, humans do, but what do *they* know?! )

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Both of you really helped a lot!